# Transfer btc from offline wallet bitcoin core to bank account

Tags: banks, money-transfer

What are there the ways to legal transfer money from offline bitcoin core wallet to my bank account, if i have more than 100 btc?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: the European Union (Germany) ,but bank in Czech Republic

Answer (score 1):

You can't transfer bitcoin to a bank account unless you live in a dursdiciton that recognises bitcoin as a legal payment, like [Japan](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/japan-receive-its-first-interest-paying-bitcoin-deposit-accounts/).

So you must find someone willing to exchange fiat currency with you, then you deposit that fiat currency into your bank.

Exchanges are one way, selling directly to another party is another.

**Note:** Exchanges often have withdrawal limits, so find them out beforehand and I would not trust them with all of that BTC at once.

I also would be extremely wary of selling it all direct without a contract, you wouldn't sell a house without a contract, this is a similar sum of money. I'd enlist a lawyer if you find a party to sell it all at once to.

The legal aspects are taxes and money laundering compliance. Exchanges should insulate you from the money laundering issue. Then taxes: in many countries, you will need to declare capital gains taxes. To be tax efficient, consult with an accountant, with >100BTC you can afford it and can't afford not to.

Comment: Above, I said that i from the European Union. And I thought about the stock exchanges, but I did not find one, where I can sale 100 btc at onec for the reason because it's a big sum in usd.
Can you advise me  the exchange for large  transaction or the country where it is legal

Comment: No, as per my new edits. Don't trust **anyone** or any **exchange** with such a huge sum at once. You will have to do it bit-by-bit, or sell all directly to a 3rd party with the help of a lawyer.

Comment: I presume you've had these coins a while, make sure your backups are up to date and secure. I'd also take that computer offline, make sure you're properly air gapped. And physical security, if that machine was stolen, could they get to the coins? Would you have half a million US dollars sitting in a metal box in your house?

Comment: I would read threads like these: https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinMarkets/comments/5yblnn/selling_large_amount_of_bitcoin_really_need_help/

Comment: you gave me food for thought. I'll think about it

Comment: ok, i have lawer, where can i find the buyer and conclude a contract?

Comment: Read the thread I posted.